# Objective-c | How to add different objects for the same index in get params request using Restkit?

Tags: objective-c, restkit, nsmutabledictionary

I'm trying to obtain a url like

myserver.com/my_content?categories[]=1&categories[]=2&categories[]=3

Using restkit 2.0

I'm creating my params object using NSMutableDictionary, but as I understand a NSMutableDictionary only allows unique keys. 
So if I do something like

```
NSMutableDictionary *queryParamsCat = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for(Category *item in arr){
    [queryParamsCat setObject:item.id_category forKey:@"categories[]"];
}
```

Only the last value of id_category will be sent as a param.
Anybody can suggest a different solution?
I'm quite a newbie in objective-c and surely there is a structure I can use but I don't know about :)

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up using an index to create a unique key and modifing the server side script to trim the index, like this

```
int i = 0;
for(TEEventCategory *item in arr){
    [queryParams setObject:item.id_category forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"categories[%d]", i]];
    i++;
}
```